# Understanding performance: mongo aggregation vs count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

If I do a count query, I get the results in <2seconds

```
db.coll.find({"A":1,"createDate":{"$gt":new Date("2011-05-21"),"$lt":new Date("2013-08-21")}}).count()
```

This uses the following index

```
db.coll.ensureIndex({"A":1,"createDate":1})
```

Similarly, there are 4 columns A,B,C,D(values are always 0 or 1) for which I run 4 count queries and get results in <10seconds.

I looked at the aggregation framework documentation and created an aggregated query to do all 4 sums together.

```
db.coll.aggregate(  { $match : {"createDate":{$gt:new Date("2013-05-21"),$lt:new Date("2013-08-21")} } },
{ $group :
                         { _id:null,
                         totalA : { $sum : "$A" },
                         totalB : {$sum: "$B},
                         totalC:{$sum: "$C"},
                         totalD:{$sum: "$D"}}} 
 )
```

I also created an index:

```
db.coll..ensureIndex({"createDate":1,"A":1,"B":1,"C":1,"D":1})
```

According to the documentation, this index covers my aggregate function. But the return of the aggregate is in ~18seconds.

I'm confused here. Is there anything basic which I missed or is there any fundamental concept lying behind which makes aggregation slower than count.
I am also concerned about the overhead due to number of queries to be fired from mongo from the code for fetching count.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, though not documented for 2.4.8 you can run an explain using the `db.runCommand` invocation:

```
db.runCommand({
    aggregate: "coll",
    pipeline: [      
        { $match : 
            {"createDate":{$gt:new Date("2013-05-21"),$lt:new Date("2013-08-21")} } 
        },
        { $group : { 
              _id:null,
              totalA: {$sum :"$A"},
              totalB: {$sum: "$B"},
              totalC: {$sum: "$C"},
              totalD: {$sum: "$D"}
        }} 
    ],
    explain: true
})
```

Which will give you some insight into what is happening.

Also, and primarily, you are comparing **apples** to **oranges**.

When you issue a `count()` on a query, it is using the cursor result properties to get the number of documents that matched.

Under aggregation, you are selecting an *extended* match and then compacting all of those results into a sum of all the items. If your initial $match has **lots** of results, then all of these need to be crunched together with $sum.

Have a look at explain, and try to conceptually understand the differences. Aggregation is great for what you generally want it to do. But maybe this isn't the best use case.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: in your case aggregation is slower because it involves more data processing while using an index mongo efficiently can calculate counts. Aggregation is meant for computing some complex results (`grouping` etc) while for simple counting `count()` suffices.

The reason for this is that aggregation in mongodb is a framework for aggregating data and is based on the concept of the data processing pipelines. Mongo  logically passes *the entire collection* into the aggregation pipeline. This is the reason there is no `explain` for aggregation as a whole (as of this writing, version `2.4`). This means there is basically one access method and the rest of the time is used for processing. But it seems there is a support for `explain` [in recent versions.](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)

You can do an early filtering in which subset of the data in a collection is used.

> > **Early Filtering**
> >
> > If your aggregation operation requires only a subset of the data in a
> >     collection, use the `$match`, `$limit`, and `$skip` stages to restrict the
> >     documents that enter at the beginning of the pipeline. When placed at
> >     the beginning of a pipeline, $match operations use suitable indexes to
> >     scan only the matching documents in a collection.
> >
> > Placing a $match pipeline stage followed by a `$sort` stage at the start
> >     of the pipeline is logically equivalent to a single query with a sort
> >     and can use an index. When possible, place $match operators at the
> >     beginning of the pipeline.

[Aggregation pipeline behaviour.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-behavior)

Comment: there is explain for aggregation, just add {explain:true} argument after the pipeline array.  And the whole collection doesn't need to be passed through if there is an index that can provide the needed values.  The problem here is aggregation is doing something different than counts were, it's actually adding values of those fields not counting how many of them are non-zero.

Comment: It is not yet released, but is coming in 2.6.

Comment: incorrect, it's available in current version of 2.4.x and has been for a few months now.

Comment: It seems to be new in version 2.5.3:http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate

Comment: it works in 2.4.6,2.4.7,2.4.8,2.4.9.  I believe the link you provide shows that starting with 2.5.2 it is required that the pipeline be an array for the option document to be properly parsed.